# Integer Array Sorting

Tags: java, arrays, file, sorting, integer

So I have this code here that takes a file and puts it into an array. What I need to do now is sort the integers in the second column from largest to smallest. Here is my code and there is a link to the data file at the bottom. I know there are sorting algorithms but I do not know how to implement them.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class sorter{
public static int id = 0;
public static int score = 0;
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner inFile = null;
          try {
  inFile = new Scanner (new File ("sorter.txt"));
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("File not found!");
  System.exit(0); 
    } 
 while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
    String str = inFile.nextLine();
    String [] parts = str.split(" ");
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];
    id = Integer.parseInt(part1);
    score = Integer.parseInt(part2);
    System.out.println(part1 + "  " +part2);
}
 }
  }
```

Here is what the output should be:

```
 /*
ID​  Score
305​ 265
306​ 262
115 ​257
311 ​256
123 ​253
116​ 246
325 ​246
321 ​245
323 ​245
113 ​243
218 ​243
208 ​242
302 ​242
112 ​239
104 ​239
110 ​238
223 ​230
213​ 229
207 ​228
203 ​224
222 ​223
    */
```

[Link to data file](http://bit.ly/1nIx1d9)

Comment: Well typically, you don't have to implement them. I would take a look at the Java Arrays API. I am sure you could come of with a way of sorting the array. Try drawing out on paper how you would sort a small array

Comment: @user3259415 are you sorting by ID or Score?

Comment: Well, you should first save every score/id, sort it then print

Comment: I think the bigger problem is keeping the id matched with the appropriate score.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class to handle this.

```
class Data {
    private int id;
    private int score;

    //constructor and other stuff
}
```

Now that you have this, create a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to hold all your datas

```
List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
    String str = inFile.nextLine();
    String [] parts = str.split(" ");
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
}
```

Now that you have this list, you can sort it. But how?

Here's the API to the rescue! There is a method in the [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class (called [`sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)) which allows you to sort your list, using a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

So what's you need is to create your comparator which will compare your objects by their scores:

```
static class DataComparator implements Comparator<Data> {
     @Override
     public int compare(Data d1, Data d2){
         return Integer.compare(d1.getScore(), d2.getScore());
     }
 }
```

Now that you have those, just call `Collections.sort` :

```
Collections.sort(list, new DataComparator());
```

Comment: So one class that creates the list and another that holds the dataComparator and the Data class? I'm pretty new at this so it's still a little confusing.

Comment: @user3259415 One class called `Data` that will hold the id and the score for each entry in your file, one to create the comparator (you could let your class implement the comparable interface but I think it's better to create a custom comparator because it's more flexible and not obvious (and you may want to change in the future!) that your datas are sorted by score and not ids. The list (`ArrayList` class) is already present in the JDK.